# PHP $_GET Variable from previous page

Tags: php, sql, variables, get

When the user clicks on a category it goes to `InsectsandPlants.php?pg=1` or the `?pg=whatevercategory`. Then on the next page I have a list of items, each one with a unique URL similar to: `view.php?aud=5` but the `?aud` changes for each item. So here's my `view.php` code:

```
<?php

    $audint=$_GET['aud'];
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM insects WHERE inid=$audint");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $lru = $row['url'];
        $title = $row['title'];
?>
<h3>You Are Viewing <?php echo $title; ?></br></br>
<embed src="<?php echo $lru; ?>" autostart="true" loop="false" controller="true" bgcolor="#000" height="42" width="300">
</br></br>
<?php
    }
?>
```

And the category page:

```
<?php

    $pgint=$_GET['pg'];

    switch($pgint)
    {
        case "1":
            echo '<li><h4>Insects and Plants</h4>';
            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM insects ORDER BY inid ASC");
        break;
        case "2":
            echo '<li><h4>Dr. Seuss</h4>';
            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DrSeuss ORDER BY inid ASC");
        break;
    }

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        array_reverse($row);
        $lru = $row['url'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $id=$row['inid'];
    ?>
```

It works for when `?pg=1` because that links to the `insects` SQL table. But I want to create a variable which changes depending on the previous page's `?pg=` number.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like any links need  to have:

```
<a href="someurl.php?blah=blah&pg=<?PHP echo $_GET['PHP'];?>">...</a>
```

This way `$_GET['pg']` will be added to the querystring of the URL and carried around the site.  It could take a bit of work if you have a lot of links and need it to be accessible globally.

If this is the case, martriay's suggestion may be better (but will take a very minor additional load on your server).

Answer (score 1):

You should store that value in a session variable.

```
session_start(); //this must be before any output, at the beginning of the script would be great

$_SESSION['pgnumber'] = $_GET['pg'];
```

this way, in any other script you use the `$_SESSION['pgnumber']` variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your $_GET['aud']; in some session variable before navigating to some place

following code may assist use

```
<?php 
session_start();

... some Code

$_SESSION['aud'] = $_GET['aud'];


... Some Code

?>
```

now whenever you need to use it you can use it as follows

```
<?php 
$aud = 0 ;

if(isset($_SESSION['aud']))
{
 $aud = $_SESSION['aud'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never ever put request data directly into sql query. Everybody will have easy access to your database. Start creating secure pages from the beginning.